Why am I experiencing an error 256 when running “brew services httpd” on macOS Sonoma (14.0)?
I had Apache and MySQL running on macOS via Homebrew for quite some time successfully.
Today, brew services list showed a problem:
Name             Status     User File
httpd            error  256 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist

brew service stop httpd, brew service start httpd as well as brew service restart httpd didn't work.
The strange thing was that I always got the status:
==> Successfully started httpd (label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)


After some searching and try and error I found this answer from toloekka in the Homebrew github page.
Solution for Apache:

Stop the Apache service directly without using Homebrew's service manager.
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
sudo apachectl stop

After this brew services list was still showing the error 256.

Restart the service through Homebrew after the manual stop.
brew services restart httpd



FYI: After a reboot brew services list will still show the error 256.
However, as long as MySql ist running, my local websites are working.
If that's all you need, good.
However in my case brew services start mysql also didn't work:
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

An "*.err log" in /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ said:
Invalid MySQL server upgrade: Cannot upgrade from 80300 to 90001

Solution for MySQL:
Caveat: MySQL is not automatically startet after a reboot.

Show Info about mysql:
brew info mysql

==> mysql: stable 9.0.1 (bottled)

This Info also contains the solution.

Follow the steps in the Caveats:
==> Caveats
Upgrading from MySQL <8.4 to MySQL >9.0 requires running MySQL 8.4 first:
 - brew services stop mysql
 - brew install mysql@8.4
 - brew services start mysql@8.4
 - brew services stop mysql@8.4
 - brew services start mysql


Verify that mysql is running:
brew services list
Name             Status  User File
          ...
mysql            started root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
mysql@8.4        none
          ...


Change Authentication for database users
Since mysql_native_password authentication plugin has been removed in Mysql 9, I suddenly couldn't establish a connection to my databases.
PhpMyAdmin threw this error:
#1524 - Plugin 'mysql_native_password' is not loaded for all database users where I had chosen Native MySQL authentication as the "Authentication plugin" in the past.
Luckily this is quite easy to fix:

Start Mysql CLI:
mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:


In the mysql> prompt, list all users using "mysql_native_password":
SELECT user, host, plugin from mysql.user WHERE plugin='mysql_native_password';

+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| user       | host      | plugin                |
+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| dbu246810  | localhost | mysql_native_password |
+------------+-----------+-----------------------+


Update mysql_native_password users to caching_sha2_password
ALTER USER 'dbu246810'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'my5ecretP4ssw0rd';


Grant the user dbu246810 all privileges to the database dbs246810
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbs246810.* TO 'dbu246810'@'localhost';


Apply the Privileges
After running the GRANT command, apply the changes with:
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;


Exit
exit;

Now you should be able to establish a connection to the databases again.




